# Sharing the Realtime Documents

Tags: google-drive-api, file-sharing, google-drive-realtime-api, multiple-accounts, google-realtime-api

I have created a playground application. I see that it creates shortcut files in my google drive. I tried to share it with incognito (because I want the doc to be available to anybody and do not know how to create another google account, so I log out into incognito). The shared link looks like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B00--A0eRH1JLTdsX2t0LWw5RE0`. But, incognito fails to view it. It says that "No preview avaialable" in what is supposed to be its google drive window and offers the log in

[image]

The key problem that I see is that playground application has the following structure, which comes from the official demo

```
function onAuthorized() {
    function onFileLoaded(doc) {display(doc)}
    gapi.drive.realtime.load(your_doc_id, onFileLoaded)
}

// App entry point -- start by authorization
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: rtClientId, scope: ['install', 'file'],
    //user_id: userId,
    immediate: !popup }, onAuthorized
);
```

which seems to demand authentication in the first place before displaying any doc. Authorization is problematic for the unsigned mode that I want my app to be available. I want to share a file and make it viewable to the general public, without the need to log in. This raises a question if incognito users are able to view or event edit my document. I also concern how to copy the doc to their account if desired: one thing is when you have created a file on your drive with my app, you can probably list the files and use `drive.copy` api to  copy desired one and other thing when you want to copy a file that is not available on your google drive and the only thing you have is its id.

BTW, can you tell me which account to use for non-incognito testing from another account? If I create the document in one account I want to see how it looks/accessible from the another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realtime API does not provide anonymous access by default.  See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/faq#does_the_realtime_api_support_anonymous_access

Answer (score 0):

**"BTW, can you tell me which account to use for non-incognito testing from another account? If I create the document in one account I want to see how it looks/accessible from the another."**

Use Chrome for one account. Use Firefox and other browsers for succeeding accounts.

**Additional note**:

Just so you have a clear understanding [what Incognito is all about](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/95464?hl=en). What it can and cannot do so you don't mix things up.

> How incognito mode works
>
> What you view
>
> Incognito is a mode that opens a new window where you can browse the
> Internet in private without Chrome saving the sites you visit. You can
> switch between an incognito window and any regular Chrome browsing
> windows you have open. You'll only be in incognito mode when you're
> using the incognito window.
>
> Be careful. Incognito mode only prevents Chrome from saving your site
> visit activity. It won't stop other sources from seeing your browsing
> activity, including:
>
> Your internet service provider Your employer (if you're using a work
> computer) The websites you visit themselves What you've downloaded
>
> Chrome won’t save a record of the files you download in incognito
> mode. However, the downloaded files will be saved to your computer’s
> Downloads folder, where you and any other users of your computer can
> see and open them, even after you close your incognito tabs.

Comment: With all respect, my question was not asking what is incognito mode. I did not understand it quite deeply but used it here to refer unsig≠dmodeunsig≠dmodeunsigned mode, when you are disconnected from google account. My question basically asks if it is possible to use my app without google account. Clearly, I can use app when I am signed in. I want to go incognito mode and use the app, view/edit the public shared files without signing in. In BTW section I asked for test account advise. Are there any disposable google accounts for testing?

Comment: the question seems clearer now. What have you figured out?

Comment: I have figured out that 1. I can share my app files and google api will throw exception if I modify read-only shared file from another account. I have figured out that google allows creating another account and chrome helps me to switch between accounts when I sign out. So, the only question that is left is if signed-out user (I called em incoginto) can use my app accessing a publically shared file without signing in?

Comment: Firefox expectedly asks me to authorize. That is the problem that I want to circument.

Comment: Interestinly, google sheets somehow allows me to access the file the incognito mode.